# Simplified molecular-input line-entry system

Tags: bioinformatics, structural-biology, 3d-structure

This may be a bit abrupt/vague question, but I didn't know how to proceed the search to get the answer.
What are the properties of a 3D biomolecule which gets ignored when a 3D biomolecule is converted to 1D representation in SMILES(Simplified molecular-input line-entry system)? two properties I found that gets neglected are linkages,interaction properties. By properties I meant isomeric count,isomeric threshold etc. Are there anymore properties that gets neglected?

Comment: Hi, could you define 3D biomolecule and provide some reference to SMILES I'm not familiar with these.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biomolecule

Comment: Shame on me for thinking that biomolecule would refer to something special....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *3D* model of a (bio)moelcule represents a physical 3-dimensions. For an experimental structure, each atom has a 3D coordinate (x, y, z) and, if determined by crystallography, an additional isotropic or aniosotropic B-factor (that models atom fluctuations).

A '1D' SMILES is not a *physical* 1-dimensional representation, and can be converted to a [graph (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) representing the chemical structure. The specification of SMILES *CAN* retain information about structural isomers, stereoisomers (cis/trans; D/L), but not conformers/rotomers, which, unlike smaller chemical structures, *IS* restricted to certain favorable regions for larger biomolecules.

By "linkage" if you mean chemical linkage such as a disulfide bond, then SMILES can retain such information. By "interactions", if you mean hydrogen-bonding, salt-bridges and even hydrophobic interactions etc., then SMILES does not code in such information, but neither does a 3D model explicitly -- they are implied from the 3D coordinates for each atom.

Thus, converting from a 3D model to SMILES, you would lose

1. Unusual bond length and bond angle: they are necessarily specified from the 3D coordinates, but in SMILES (or the subsequent graph), they are taken as 'ideal'.
2. [B-factor or temperature factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye%E2%80%93Waller_factor)
3. Rotomers: e.g. Proteins have favored dihedral angles in both [backbone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramachandran_plot) and side chains, which is not specified in SMILES.
4. "Interactions": certain intramolecular interaction that is inevitable (e.g. salicylaldehyde) is implied in both SMILES and a 3D model. Most others can only be inferred in the 3D model.

Comment: can you please tell me how you came to know about these facts?? I tried to find the properties of a 3D biomolecule but couldn't find it.. Is there any book I should follow?

Comment: I happen to be a structural biologist. You could check out some books on 'Structural bioinformatics' or 'Chemical Informatics', and download visualization software to play with the 3D coordinates from one of Protein Data Bank(s). (http://www.wwpdb.org/) RCSB hosts a very good overview http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/101/static101.do?p=education_discussion/Looking-at-Structures/intro.html

Comment: Okay, I have something to say if you don't mind, can I get your email so that I can contact you when I am stuck with something?

Comment: I don't mind. My email is on my profile. There should be many experts here on the forum, too.